# Помощь в создании алгоритма Python 3 pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

Пишу игру, однако затрудняюсь в создании функции, отрисовывающей текстовый label на экране и потихоньку поднимающей его вверх пока тот не дойдет до края экрана и не исчезнет. Если кто-нибудь объяснит мне алгоритм, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Шаг 1: Вам нужно создать объект шрифта:

```
textfont = pygame.font.Font("*нужный вам шрифт*", *размер шрифта*)
```

Шаг 2: Нужно отрисовать текст через этот шрифт:

```
textsurface = textfont.render(*надпись*, 1 (я не знаю что это за параметр), *цвет, обозначается с помощью 3х чисел*)
```

Шаг 3: Рисуете текст на экран:

```
screen.blit(textsurface, (*X*, *Y*))
```

Шаг 4: Где то в коде обновляете координату текста и повторяете шаг 3.

Также если вам нужна документация, вот она: https://www.pygame.org/docs